# ColdFusion : 2 CheckBoxes : Allow 1 Selected : CSS Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, forms, checkbox, coldfusion-2016

I have a form which has 2 check boxes available for selection.

It is for an activity - where 1 can be a player or a goalie. But not both.
But Some activities do not have a Goalie.

But they can only check one of the 2 on same row.  I tried an ID in the checkbox.

I know I can do with a Radio button. But sometimes only 1 checkbox is there. As the activity may not have a Goalie. And if only 1 Radio u can't turn on/off.

I can double check things on the backend, but I'm wondering if there is some easy CSS/Javascript to only allow one of the check boxes at a time per row.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="PLAYER" id="#shinid#" value="#shinid#"> 
<input type="checkbox" name="GOALIE" id="#shinid#" value="#shinid#">
```

Comment: Use ColdFusion code to decide which type of input to include in the generated HTML page. If only one option then include a checkbox, if more than one then include radio buttons.

Comment: Yea I did that on the back end.  I punt them back if they select 2 on same line.  If I switch to Radio it needs to handle differently in the backend.  So I prefer to just handle 1 way in back end.  I was hoping for an easy HTML/Java trick.